# ffmpeg output blank image files on CentOS 6.4

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, capture

0I am trying to capture thumbnail images from a video by using ffmpeg.

So I typed command like Below.

```
ffmpeg -i MyVideo.mp4 -s 480x270 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/600 thumb%03d.png
```

just like what ffmpeg official site suggested.

The length of `MyVideo.mp4` is `01:46:03`, So I expected total 10 images from it.

(because `fps=fps=1/600` part means 10minute 1piece.)

But output is 12 pieces, and especially first one is broken.

When I check it's information in GUI, it says "failed to load information".

Comment: Please ask your FFmpeg command line questions on [SU], and don't forget to include the full, uncut console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
because fps=fps=1/600 part means 1minute 1piece.
```

This means `1/600` frames per second, or one frame every 600 seconds.

You probably want `fps=fps=1/60`

Comment: ah, yes. my mistake. I means 1piece/10minutes.

Comment: but my main problem is first shot is totally black and broken,

Comment: I solved this as adjusting start second like -ss 00:00:03